# Is there a possibility to display an &auml; as an ä in Vim?

Tags: vim, html-entities

Is there a possibility to display characters in a Vim window (that is: on the screen) that are different from the underlying characters in the buffer?

For example, if filetype is set to html, I'd (sometimes) like to see html-entities replaced by their humanly readable character (for example an `ä` instead of `&auml;`). Of course, this would entail that the rest of the line after the entity would have to be "shifted" to the left. If this is possible somehow, I'd appreciate any hint into the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using 7.3 or newer, then you can make use of the [conceal](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version7.txt.html#new-conceal) feature to do that.  For example:

```
syntax match Entity "&auml;" conceal cchar=ä
```

Comment: Wonderful! I was waiting for something like this for year.... and missed it when it finally came. Just for completness' sake: I had also to `:set conceallevel=1` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try a plugin:

html_umlaute : replaces german Umlaute with their HTML Encoding on saving

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=907

html_french : view html entities as accented characters for French

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1933